# How to add sprite clicked on collision without rects?

Tags: python, pygame

I am new to pygame, not python and I am trying to make a alien shooter game, and i want collision between the crosshairs and the sprite. I want to collide a circle with a alien image and a shape? I don't want rects, just pure 'click on sprite and disappear'. Is there any way to do this? Here is the code:

```
"""
Alien_Shooter

Description:
 a game to shoot aliens

"""


import pygame
import tsk
import random
pygame.init()





WIDTH = 1018
HEIGHT = 573

w = pygame.display.set_mode([WIDTH, HEIGHT])
c = pygame.time.Clock()
shooting= False


invaderImage = []
invader_X = []
invader_Y = []
invader_Xchange = []
invader_Ychange = []
no_of_invaders = 8

turn = False

for num in range(no_of_invaders):
    alien = pygame.image.load('SquidMan.png')
    alien = pygame.transform.scale(alien, (100,100))
    alien_hb = pygame.Rect(200, 500, 50, 50)
    #collide = pygame.Rect.colliderect(player_rect, mouse)



    invaderImage.append(alien)

    invader_X.append(random.randint(64, 737))
    invader_Y.append(random.randint(30, 180))

    invader_Xchange.append(0)
    invader_Ychange.append(1)

def invader(x, y, i):
    w.blit(invaderImage[i], (x, y))





drawing = True
while drawing:
    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
            drawing = False
    
        if e.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            shooting = True
        else:
            shooting = False
        
    #collide = pygame.Rect.colliderect(alien_rect, center_rect)

    
    x, y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    #print(x,y)
    
    if shooting == True:
        # gives the flashing effect when shooting
        color = (0,0,0)
    else:
        color = (255,255,255)
    
    for i in range(no_of_invaders):
        invader_X[i] += invader_Xchange[i]


    # movement of the invader
    for i in range(no_of_invaders):

        

        invader_Y[i] += invader_Ychange[i]
    

        invader(invader_X[i], invader_Y[i], i)
        
        
        
        
    
    
    line1 = pygame.draw.line(w, color, (x,y), (350, 700), 3)
    line2 = pygame.draw.line(w, color, (x,y), (650, 700), 3)
    # crosshares
    center = pygame.draw.circle(w,color, (x, y), 10, 2)
    pygame.draw.line(w, color, (x,y), (x+20, y), 3)
    pygame.draw.line(w, color, (x,y), (x-20, y), 3)
    
    ####################
    #        |         #
    #      --o--       #
    #        |         #
    ####################
    
    pygame.draw.line(w, color, (x,y), (x, y+20), 3)
    pygame.draw.line(w, color, (x,y), (x, y-20), 3)


    

    pygame.display.flip()

    c.tick(20)
    w.fill((0,0,0))
```

I tried to fix this but I am not sure how to do it without rects

Answer (score -1):

You calculate the distance between the mouse click (mouse_x, mouse_y) and the center of the sprite (alien_center_x, alien_center_y) using the Pythagorean theorem: distance = sqrt((alien_center_x - mouse_x)**2 + (alien_center_y - mouse_y)**2). If this distance is less than a certain threshold, which could be half the width of the sprite (essentially its radius if it's roughly circular), then you consider it a hit.

Here’s a bit of code to illustrate this approach

```
import pygame
import math

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))

# Load your alien sprite here
alien = pygame.image.load('alien.png').convert_alpha()
alien_rect = alien.get_rect(center=(400, 300))

running = True
while running:
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        running = False
    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        distance = math.sqrt((alien_rect.centerx - mouse_pos[0]) ** 2 + 
  (alien_rect.centery - mouse_pos[1]) ** 2)
        if distance < 50:  # Adjust this value to fit your sprite size
            print("Hit!")

screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
screen.blit(alien, alien_rect)
pygame.display.flip()
```

Just replace 'alien.png' with your sprite and adjust the hit detection radius as needed.